# Sqlite.SqliteException Could not open database file filepath (CannotOpen) in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms application and using SQlite for my database.

Currently I have created a new database using the DB Browser for SQLite.

In my code behind, when my application initially runs, I try to connect to SQLiteAsyncConnection and give the path to the local folder (on the PC) where I created the new database via sqlite browser.
This step always throws the error "Could not open database file".

Following lines I have tried but it all throws error:

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\hp\\Data\\CheckList.db";
                SqlConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);

string path = @"C:\Users\hp\\Data\CheckList.db";
                SqlConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);

string path = "C://Users//hp//Data//CheckList.db";
                SqlConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
```

All the above lines fail for me.

Also attaching screenshot for reference.[image]

Any help or suggestions would be great!!!..

Comment: your mobile app has no concept of the desktop file system and cannot retrieve files from it at runtime.  You need to include your pre-populated DB as part of your project so it will be deployed with your app.

Comment: You can try copy your SQLite database in your application root folder, then try it again, here is the same thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086010/sqlite-database-connection-error-xamarin-forms-pcl