# SQLiteConnection always failing with "Could not open database file"

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I'm getting constant fail with the following code:

```
_dbpath = Path.Combine(Settings.Default.SDCARD_DB, "MyApp.db");
bool a = File.Exists(_dbpath); //returns true

var = new SQLiteConnection(_dbpath, false); //throws exception
```

Exception is:

> e = {SQLite.SQLiteException: Could not open database file:
> /storage/emulated/0/MyApp/MyApp.db (CannotOpen)   at
> SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor (SQLite.SQLiteConnectionString
> connectionString) [0x00094] in :0
> at ...

The code works on my Android tablet but throws the exception on my Samsung phone. I've tried different locations for the db, tried different dbs but always the same problem.

Other

- VS 2022.
- Xamarin Forms
- Android v12

Any thoughts of where my problem might be?

Comment: You can try to copy your SQLite database in your application root folder, then config the folder,you can also refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086010/sqlite-database-connection-error-xamarin-forms-pcl

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't work in the application root folder, but I think that it is a folder permissions problem rather than a sqlite problem. Will keep exploring in that direction.

Comment: Yes,I think so.Have you declare `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`?